# Synchronize window.setTimeout callback

Tags: javascript, synchronization, settimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("1");
}
console.log("2");
```

Basically, what I want to output "1" before "2". How do I synchronize the callback function with the current "caller" thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't hold up the thread in JavaScript (other than the `alert` and `confirm` built-ins), so the only ways to make your `console.log("2")` happen after your `console.log("1")` are:

1. Put it in the timeout function:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("1");
       console.log("2");
   }, delay);
   ```

   ...or in another function that that timeout function calls, although as you already have a function for the `setTimeout`, it's unclear (other than code organization) why you'd need a separate one.
2. Put it in a separate function you pass to `setTimeout` with a longer delay:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("1");
   }, delay);
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("2");
   }, longerDelay);
   ```

   ...being careful that `longerDelay` really is sufficiently longer than `delay` that you don't end up with a bit of chaos around scheduling.

Note I said "the thread" above. Unless you're using [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), which have a specific syntax, JavaScript on browsers is *single-threaded*. Two JavaScript functions cannot run simultaneously, and aside from edge case browser bugs around `alert` and ajax completions and the like (at least some versions of Firefox run your ajax completion callback while you have a function waiting on `alert`; strange but true, and nothing you can rely on cross-browser or even cross-version), you can't pause one JavaScript function in its tracks while another JavaScript function runs.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed reply. What I'm really doing is writing QUnit test cases for asynchronous functions. I have a bunch of test cases each having async function call. But when I debug it appears that until all sync code is not finished, no async call is executed. But what I wanted to finish each test case synchronously including both its sync and async code.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("1");
    callback();
}
function callback(){
   console.log("2");
}
```